# Getting a word from a set in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

I have a dataframe column 'address' with values like this in each row:

```
3466B, Jerome Avenue, The Bronx, Bronx County, New York, 10467, United States, (40.881836199999995, -73.88176324294639)

Jackson Heights 74th Street - Roosevelt Avenue (7), 75th Street, Queens, Queens County, New York, 11372, United States, (40.74691655, -73.8914737373454)
```

I need only to keep the value Bronx / Queens / Manhattan / Staten Island from each row.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those values always in the same place?

Comment: No they don't actually, but for each row there is always an unique value in those that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One option is this, assuming the values are always in the same place. Using `.split(', ')[2]`

```
"3466B, Jerome Avenue, The Bronx, Bronx County, New York, 10467, United States, (40.881836199999995, -73.88176324294639)".split(', ')[2]
```

If the source file is a CSV (Comma-separated values), I would have a look at pandas and `pandas.read_csv('filename.csv')` and leverage all the nice features that are in pandas.

If the values are not at the same position and you need only a is in set of values or not:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["The Bronx", "Queens", "Man"])
df.isin(["Queens", "The Bronx"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column, let's call it 'district' and then populate it like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':["3466B, Jerome Avenue, The Bronx, Bronx County, New York, 10467, United States, (40.881836199999995, -73.88176324294639)",
"Jackson Heights 74th Street - Roosevelt Avenue (7), 75th Street, Queens, Queens County, New York, 11372, United States, (40.74691655, -73.8914737373454)"]})

districts = ['Bronx','Queens','Manhattan', 'Staten Island']
df['district'] = ''

for district in districts:
    df.loc[df['address'].str.contains(district) , 'district'] = district
        
print(df)
```